# How to Handle Scene Graph Creation

Tags: architecture, d, scene, scenegraph

I am currently designing a scene graph, but I came across a problem.

When creating a scene graph, I create an unrolled linked list to hold child nodes. The scene graph is designed to allow for the use of custom allocators, which the scene is initialized with and carries as a member variable.

As it stands, I have a number of functions called `make*` that take in a scene, plus any parameters the node may have (ie. `makeGroup(scene, null)`). My question is this: What methods are available to me to create the nodes whilst removing unnecessary bloat?

I have come to two solutions so far:

1. Pass the allocator to the node only at creation and destruction. The node itself does not retain a reference to the allocator. Only the scene that created it does. This requires some extra noise during the creation process, though it can be easily hidden within the `make` functions.
2. Allow the node to carry a reference to the allocator itself, increasing dependencies within the Node class, as well as adding another member to the class.

Comment: All the make* functions can become constructors I guess...

Comment: I could, but that implicitly implies the second solution because D doesn't allow you to pass parameters to the destructor.

Comment: Well, you could use struct, or rely on the GC to delete unused references...

Comment: I'd prefer not to use the GC (hence the allocators). And each node allocates a list for its children, so I need to clean that up somehow. I'd prefer not to have to use a two-stage deallocation process for each node.

Comment: And I presume you do not want to use structs?

Comment: I do not. Using structs precludes the use of inheritance without lots of template boilerplate, and does not allow you to use polymorphism. Also, I'd prefer to be able to pass nodes by reference, saving on typing and reducing a point of error.